# React -ComponentDidMount Working but again onclick of each response giving error

Tags: reactjs

**See my code is on page load i have 3 links and one is contact link and when i click on contact link ,there is a componentDidMount and it call users api and i get response successfully and is saved to state and i try to render name from the response in my child component named GetDetailsOfContact and along with name it do have a button to get the details of each user . When you click the button nearby name it carries the id and have a function which have api to fetch the details of user with that id,it too works fine . I do have another child component named GetDetailsContentSection which again take the prop as the response i get from fetch api with id,but i am not able to render,its giving below error **

please find my App.js

````
import React from "react"
import ListTodos from "./ListTodos"
import {Route,Link,BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
import Contact from "./Contact"
import Profile from "./Profile"
import Home from "./Home"

class App extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Router>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/contact">Contacts</Link>
            <Link to="/profile">My Profile</Link>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </Router>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App```
        And i have Contact Component



    import React from "react"
    import GetDetailsOfContact from "./GetDetailsOfContact"
    import GetDetailsContentSection from "./GetDetailsContentSection"

    class Contact extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state={
                data:[],
                fetchUser:[]
            }
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        }

        handleChange(id){
            console.log(id);
             fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+id)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ fetchUser:data }));
        }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ data:data,fetchUser:[] }));
      }
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                <p>This is my contact page</p>
                <GetDetailsOfContact data={this.state.data}  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
                 <GetDetailsContentSection data={this.state.fetchUser} />
                </div>


            )
        }
    }

    export default Contact
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    import React from "react"

    class GetDetailsOfContact extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                <ul>
                {
                    this.props.data.map(item=>{
                        return(<li key={item.id}>{item.name}
                        <button onClick={()=>this.props.handleChange(item.id)}>edit</button></li>)
                    })
                }
                </ul>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default GetDetailsOfContact
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    import React from "react"

    class GetDetailsContentSection extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                <p>This is the details of particular contact selected</p>
                <ul>
                {
                    this.props.data.map(item=>{
                        return(<li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
                    })
                }
                </ul>
                <div>

                </div>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default GetDetailsContentSection



        But am getting this error 
 `The above error occurred in the <GetDetailsOfContact> component: in GetDetailsOfContact (created by Contact)
             in div (created by Contact) in Contact in Route (created by App) in Router (created by BrowserRouter) in BrowserRouter
             (created by App) in div (created by App) in App Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior`
````

Comment: The actual error is missing from our question.

Comment: Instead of `handleChange(id){...}` can you try: `handleChange = (id) => {` The arrow function will automatically bind `this`. Since you have not posted the actual error I think this may be the problem (if the error was cannot read property setState of undfined or setState is not a function.

Comment: @HMR i tried with arrow function for the handleChange,but no luck.this is the error am getting on id click
The above error occurred in the <GetDetailsOfContact> component: in GetDetailsOfContact (created by Contact)
             in div (created by Contact) in Contact in Route (created by App) in Router (created by BrowserRouter) in BrowserRouter
             (created by App) in div (created by App) in App Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior

Comment: You only posted where the error occurred but not the error. Can you check the console (F12) for some info?

Comment: @HMR i am just trying my code in scrimba,so this is the error am getting in console.

Comment: What if you put the code in [a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? you can use [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/new). when you save it it'll create a new url. I do advice you to use `create-react-app` and vscode if you want to debug a react project.

Comment: @HMR i had created the same in https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-microservice-4jem7

Comment: @HMR https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-microservice-4jem7?fontsize=14

Comment: GetDetailsOfContact.js is an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error

```
    The fetchUser is an object so the conditional rendering fetchUser.length > 0 && <Component /> will not do any component render as (object.length = undefined) > 0 = false.
    Due to the above your child component will not have an array to map() so just show the object there.
```